# Payoff of barrier options

Tags: options, call, barrier

I was reading a research paper recently and the author defined payoffs of Up-and-Out and Down-and-Out barrier call options as max[0, ST - K]I(m < H) and max[0, ST - K]I(M > H) respectively.

K is the strike price, H is the barrier, spot price process is defined as S = {St, 0 < t < T}, m is defined as inf{St, 0 < t < T} and M is defined as sup{St, 0 < t < T}.
What I do not understand is the conditions of the indicators. For UO shouldn't it be I(M < H) because if the supremum is below the barrier then the price on the whole interval is below the barrier and the Up-and-Out option is active? And for DO it seems logical to me to use I(m > H) instead of I(M > H).

Can anyone please clarify it?

Comment: Up-and-out should be $[S_T-K]^{+}(M<H)$ whilst Down-and-out should be $[S_T-K]^{+}(m>H)$. The pay-off at maturity in your question looks more like Down-and-In and Up-and-In respectively.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll just assume then that there is a typo in the original paper.

Comment: Could you also reference the paper pls? I would be interested to take a look.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/seminarier/reports/K-exjobb09/090601a.pdf